# Where are the Review items

Tags: support

I recently passed 2000 and now `review` shows 63 items to review.

Where and what are they?
I have looked a Close Votes, First Posts etc.

How can I reset this to 0 so I can have a clean start?

Comment: What do you mean by a clean start?

Comment: I assume the 63 items I cannot find are old, not added in the last few days, and have presumably already been reviewed.

Answer (score 1):

I think this Q&A at meta.SE addresses the issue (if I understand you correctly):

[Review Items counter is stuck](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236412/review-items-counter-is-stuck)